# How do I get the IP of only one Interface

Tags: linux, ifconfig

When I tried ifconfig it gives me the whole all the information regarding the Network Adapter.

I tried :

```
system( "ifconfig -a | grep inet | "
          "sed 's/\\([ ]*[^ ]*\\)\\([ ]*[^ ]*\\).*$/\\1 \\2/' "
          " > address.txt" ) ;
```

which output two Ips :

```
  inet  addr:17.24.17.229
  inet  addr:127.0.0.1
```

But I need just the 1st one , How can I filter this out.

Comment: Um... I'm sure C++ has some facility to fetch the first line only, doesn't it?

Comment: @Pekka: But is that what he really needs ? What if `127.0.0.1` comes first for some reason ?

Comment: I don't see any connection between this connection and C++.  I don't even see any connection between this question and software development, it's more of a network administration question.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: I believe the OP wasn't happy with his previous answers regarding how to do the same thing programatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't look at all of the adapters, just the one you want.

```
system( "ifconfig -a eth0 | grep inet | "
          "sed 's/\\([ ]*[^ ]*\\)\\([ ]*[^ ]*\\).*$/\\1 \\2/' "
          " > address.txt" ) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

You might use `head` but...

I might be mistaking of course, but my guess is that you don't really need the **first** one.

You're probably looking for the one that is connected to the gateway (or the Internet).

As far as I know, the order of the IP addresses or interfaces is **unspecified**.

What do you want to achieve exactly ?

If you want to know what interface is "connected to the internet", a more reliable approach is to find the interface which has the **default route** (using `route`) then to use `ifconfig <interface>` to directly get the correct IP address.

Comment: however maybe the complexity of this is lost on this user, as I just noticed I asked him the same thing in his [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997428/how-can-i-get-the-ip-address-of-system) :)

Comment: @Pekka: So did I, actually ;)

Comment: @Pekka: Great point - tried the OP's script, and lo and behold, the loopback was on the first line. Not a very useful interface, that. So I grepped that out, and the management network interface came up next. Not useful either. Next, the bridge interface for my VMs. Uh-oh. Wouldn't it be more useful to check the output of `route`? It does have the default gateway there.

Comment: @Piskvor that sounds like a good idea! The OP needs to clarify what he really needs.

Comment: @Piskvor: I just added a suggestion to use `route` as well. That's also how I usually do.

Comment: route|sed -n '/^default/s/.* //p' == perfect!

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `iproute2`'s `ip`:

```
ip -o addr show dev eth0 | while read IFNUM IFNAME ADDRTYPE ADDR REST; do [ "$ADDRTYPE" == "inet" ] && echo $ADDR; done
9.87.65.43/21
```

(Not only because it's easier to parse, but it'll also show e.g. secondary IPs, which `ifconfig` can't.)

Answer (score 2):

To get the IP address of a single interface (`eth0`) in Linux:

`ip address show dev eth0`

You can pipe this through grep using a IP regular expression and select just the first address found:

`ip a show dev eth0 | grep -oP '(?:\b\.?(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){4}' | head -1`

This device might have more than one IP address associated with it so you could have to adjust the `| head -1` bit depending on which address you would like to pick. You will also have to filter out broadcast addresses.

Answer (score 1):

you can reduce the use of `grep` and `head`

```
ifconfig -a | sed -nr -e '/inet\b/{s|^.*inet\s+addr:(.[^ \t]*).*|\1|;h}' -e '${x;p}'
```

Answer (score 0):

If the output of `ifconfig` or `ip` ever changes, your program will break.

Why not not just use the `SIOCGIFCONF` `ioctl()` and get it directly from the source?

ETA:  It's also unsafe to assume that any given system will have just one loopback interface and just one Ethernet with a single address.

Answer (score 0):

How about 'ifconfig eth0'?

Comment: ifconfig has been deprecated, if not removed, from most modern Linux distros. Which is a shame because often one only wants the details about ONE interface. (I wonder if that could be considered a bug in ip.)

Answer (score 0):

`hostname -I | awk '{print $1}'`